# Show multiple ng-modals with dynamic content on respective click events in the same component/page using <ng-content>

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular2 modals to dynamically create content using `<ng-content>`. 
Let me explain to you what I have done.

I have created Modal Component with a selector say 'app-modal' and its template contains the `<ng-content>` in which I will load the content dynamically.

Now, I have another component in which I need to show particular modal on different click with dynamic content.

So, I would be having two "app-modal" on my page with different content.

I need to know the approach, how do I refer to the respective modal that I want to show on a particular click.

Currently, when I click any link, it always opens the first modal on the page.
I know I am missing something or a way in which we can refer to the respective modals that we want to show.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code in my **modal.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './app-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-modal.component.css']
})
export class AppModalComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('content') modal: ElementRef;
    public modalClose: NgbActiveModal;
  constructor(public modalService: NgbModal) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    open() {
    this.modalClose = this.modalService.open(this.modal, { windowClass: 'modal-wrapper' });
  }


  close(){
    this.modalClose.close();
  }
}
```

Code in **modal.component.html**

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <ng-content select=".modal-body"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".modal-footer"></ng-content>

</ng-template>
```

Below is the code for my **page.component.html** in which I am calling the click method to show respective modals.

```
<h3 (click)="openModalOne()">Open Modal One</h3>
<h3 (click)="openModalTwo()">Open Modal Two</h3>

    <app-modal>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Body of modal 1.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            Footer of modal 1.
        </div>
    </app-modal>


    <app-modal>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Body of modal 2.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            Footer of modal 2.
        </div>
    </app-modal>
```

Below is my **page.component.ts** code

```
import { AppModalComponent } from './app-modal/app-modal.component';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private modalService: NgbModal ) {}

  @ViewChild(AppModalComponent)
  private modal: AppModalComponent;

   openModalOne() {
    console.log("Inside open modal one");
    this.modal.open();
  }
  openModalTwo() {
    console.log("Inside open modal two");
    this.modal.open();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ViewChild('varName')` with a template variable `(<tag #varName>)` to get a specific element when you have more than one of the same type. You should try to avoid direct access anyway, use bindings instead if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Parshwa for your response. I found another way to implement it as per my requirement.

Comment: Post your answer so another developer can get an idea for same